# Resizing kendo items

Tags: javascript, angular6

I want to change size of kendo items for example on 40px. But when I try do this, nothing happens. What is also problem for me, I need only one button, which has normal (grey) color on the start, but after mouse clicks should toggle between pink and green with changing side of kendo items (like below).  After clicks kendo items also should change color background.Everything in Angular 6.

I am not really know how to resize kendo items. I tried do this like in follow code, but it's not working fine.

```
<button class = "k-icon k-button" [ngClass] = "'nx-button toggle-button accept'">
  Accept
<span class="k-icon k-i-check-outline k-i-checkmark-outline accept"></span>
</button>

<button class = "k-icon k-button" [ngClass] = "'nx-button toggle-button denied'">
    Denied
  <span class="k-icon k-i-check-outline k-i-checkmark-outline denied"></span>
  </button>

.nx-button.toggle-button.denied {
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    background: pink;
    width : 150px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nx-button.toggle-button.accept {
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    background: greenyellow;
    width : 150px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.k-icon.k-i-check-outline.k-i-checkmark-outline.denied { 
    position: absolute;
    background: pink;
    margin: -22px 10px 0 -75px;
    border-radius:40px;
    // width: 25px;
    // height: 25px;
    width: auto !important;
    -moz-min-width: 40px;
    -ms-min-width: 40px;
    -o-min-width: 40px;
    -webkit-min-width: 40px;
}

.k-icon.k-i-check-outline.k-i-checkmark-outline.accept { 
    position: absolute;
    background: greenyellow;
    margin: -22px 10px 0 75px;
    border-radius:40px;
    // width: 25px;
    // height: 25px;
    -moz-min-width: 40px;
    -ms-min-width: 40px;
    -o-min-width: 40px;
    -webkit-min-width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Kendo Button](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/button/) [toggleable functionality](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/button/toggleable/) and add some additional custom logic for adding and removing the custom classes and changing the text depending on the desired behavior, e.g.:

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hylnlg?file=app/app.component.ts)